# i've hit a bunch of keys at the same time accidentally and now my brightness buttons are not working on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, brightness

my dog walked on my laptop and now the brightness keys are not working. they are f6 and f7 for me. the sound keys also didn't work but I fixed them by going to settings > keyboard > shortcuts and I fixed them here but there was no brightness option there. how do I fix this?  note that when I hold fn and I press f6/ f7 I can change my brightness, but i don't wanna do that. i want to repair my computer.

[system information in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khgK7.png)

Comment: yes @guiverc this problem has been going on for more than a day.

Comment: What model is your laptop? It probably has a function lock button on the keyboard somewhere that switches the functionality for your F keys.

Comment: @Baa dell Vostro 15 3000. that's what it says.

Comment: @sweetiesakura Press FN + ESC

Comment: @Baa nope. didn't work.

Comment: @Baa this is really annoying me. i've tried multiple combinations of keys but it's just not fixing it.

Comment: @sweetiesakura I tried checking the manual for your laptop but there's a lot of versions for the 3000 model and the one I checked had birghtness on F11 and F12 keys so it's probably not the right one, could you run `sudo dmidecode | less` and add System Information part of the output to your question please?

Comment: sure. i took a picture of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137362/discussion-between-sweetie-sakura-and-baa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some laptop models have a Function Lock button that will switch the funcionality of the F keys from the traditional F1 - 12 to the function of the icons.

Your laptop model is Dell Vostro 15 3500, assuming I've got the right picture, the FN Lock is on the Escape key so if you press FN + ESC it should switch the functionality again.

But since that hasn't worked, [the manual](https://dl.dell.com/topicspdf/vostro-15-3500-laptop_owners-manual_en-us.pdf) says you can also change it from the BIOS:

1. Enter the BIOS by turning off your laptop, then turn it back on and press F12.
2. Navigate to POST Behaviour > FN Lock > Set this to `Lock Mode Secondary`.
3. Press ESC to exit and choose Save.

Comment: what do you mean when you say navigate to 'post behaviour' ? will there be a tab called post behaviour? i need to know before trying. i will note this down.

Comment: Yes the manual suggestions as much, although I haven't seen it myself

Comment: hey! it actually worked. thanks for taking the time to help me out! :)))

Comment: no worries glad to help :)

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct by clicking the gray checkmark, since it solved your issue.

Comment: @OrganicMarble oh i did that. i don't know why it didn't turn green before.